# Using php “fputcsv” to save an array (that includes cells with special charcters) created by papa.unparse, as a csv

Tags: javascript, php, csv, papaparse

Although there are various php/csv answers on stackOverflow, I cannot see an answer to my exact problem.
I have the following php script, which is called from javascript – via AJAX XMLHttpRequest()  to save an array as a csv file. I use javascript to separate the  rows by the symbol “~” and the cells separated by commas. My problem is that some array cells contain special characters. I have tried many different ways, without success, to use JavaScript to enclose the cell text in double quotes and to use a different separator (ie instead of a comma). I would however prefer to use Papa.unparse to create a single variable that contains the array as a fully formatted csv. That variable correctly encloses the cells with commas etc in a set of double quotes. However, I do not know if there is a way to change my current php script to accept a single (csv formatted) variable to write as a csv file.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["Row"])){
    $rlist = $_POST["Row"];
    $fname =($_POST["Fname"]);
    $rArray = explode("~",$rlist);
    $totalR = count($rArray);
    $fp = fopen($fname, 'w');
    for($i =0; $i<$totalR;$i++){
        $row = $rArray[$i];
        $srow =explode(",",$row); 
        array_push($srow,"\n");
        fputcsv($fp,$srow); 
    }
fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

Comment: 1. You're going to have to be more specific about what these "special characters" are. 2. Don't break the format. CSV is fairly flexible on pretty much everything except "rows are delimited by line breaks". If you're delimiting with something other than `\n` then it's not going to play nice with most CSV encoders/decoders.

Comment: Thanks for your time. The main problem is the comma - but the data is input by the user - some in Spanish with their own characters. So I want it to be as robust as possible. I am assuming the papa.unpase is fairly robust in creating the enclosed quotes and \n. So I just need to know how to take a variable that is in full csv format (as created by pap.unparse) and amend the php script above to handle a single variable.

Answer (score 0):

Alter the php so that the comma separator that it is searching for is any odd sequence of characters

```
$srow =explode(",",$row);
```

Alter to

```
$srow =explode("<XX>",$row);
```

Then change the config of papa.unparse to:

```
{
    delimiter: "<XX>",
    header: false,
    newline: "~",
}
```